# How to create one function for all triggers by using Dynamic table name in trigger functionh

Tags: postgresql, triggers, dynamic-sql

I have 3 triggers for 3 history table and 3 functions for it.
how to create one function for all triggers by using  Dynamic table name in trigger function.so that i can pass table name dynamically and insert the records accordindly whether old or new..

### sample 1 trigger and 1 function code for reference :

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname           text NOT NULL,
    salary            integer
);

CREATE TABLE emp_audit(
    operation         char(1)   NOT NULL,
    stamp             timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid            text      NOT NULL,
    empname           text      NOT NULL,
    salary integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in emp_audit to reflect the operation performed on emp,
        -- making use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'D', now(), user, OLD.*;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'U', now(), user, NEW.*;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'I', now(), user, NEW.*;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit`enter code here`
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION process_emp_audit();
```

I want to use from static istory table to dynamic table so that i can use one function for all 3 triggers. how to change this below insert statements dynamically.

```
INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'D', now(), user, OLD.*;
 INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'U', now(), user, NEW.*;
INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'I', now(), user, NEW.*;
```

Comment: Then you need to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: how to use dynamic sql to the below insert statements . so that one function for all 3 triggers on 3 history tables.

Comment: how to use dynamic sql to insert into dynamic history table so that i can store dml records into hsitory table ..i have 3 history table and 3 function. want to have 1 fucntion for 3 triggers and should use dynamic hsitory table in the insert statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL and arguments to the trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
   ...
   EXECUTE
      format(
         'INSERT INTO %I SELECT ''I'', current_timestamp, %L, ($1::%I.%I).*',
         TG_ARGV[0], current_user, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME
      )
      USING NEW;
   ...
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit_trig
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE FUNCTION audit('emp_audit');
```

The first argument that you pass to the trigger function will be available as [`TG_ARGV[1]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) inside the function.

Use [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to construct an SQL string while avoiding the risk of SQL injection. The placeholder `%I` is for SQL identifiers, `%L` is for string literals.

`$1` will be replaced by the first argument to `USING`.

Comment: I got error : NULL value cannot format as sql identifier

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the index starts at 0. Fixed.

Comment: i got error "relation emp_audit does not exist." could you place code in fiddleand execute ..

Comment: Of course you have to create the table :^)

Comment: above code works fine without schema. now i added schema "abc" to all objects like abc.emp, abc.emp_audit, abc.audit() and in final trigger code passing arguments also i mention EXECUTE FUNCTION audit('abc.emp_audit');. I got error relation ship does not exist.. could you please help me how to use the same function and trigger when schema name is used for tables, and function

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new question for that.

Comment: New question  created -- Error: Relation “abc.emp_audit” does not exist. when i add schema name in all objects. it was working fine without schema. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If you want fully dynamic without the need for dynamic SQL then you can convert and store the complete row as JSON(B) or a hstore. The following demonstrates (along with a couple additional auditing columns):

```
-- Audit table and Trigger function
create table audit_table ( aud_id integer generated always as identity
                         , action        text 
                         , table_name    text 
                         , action_tstz   timestamptz default clock_timestamp()
                         , row_data      jsonb                         
                         , user_name     text        default user
                         , sql_stmt      text        default current_query()
                         ) ; 

create or replace 
function dml_action_audit()
 returns trigger
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    insert into audit_table( action
                           , table_name
                           , row_data) 
       select tg_op
            , tg_table_schema ||'.' || tg_table_name
            , case when tg_op = 'INSERT' 
                   then row_to_json(new.*)
                   else row_to_json(old.*)
              end ; 
      return null;
end; 
$$;
```

And used the standard table with function definition. It also leads to a couple interesting possibilities. See [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a1f4515e3200e3b9094669a40e36590).